# How to connect a node to mainnet

Tags: mainnet

Once someone compiles eos.io software from github, what is the process of connecting it to the main net so that all cleos calls can be pointed to the localhost instead of block producers? Also anyone has the minimum system requirements for such a node?

Answer (score 3):

First you need the genesis.json file that matches everyone else's.  Then you will need to launch with it (only the first time you run nodeos, after that don't use it)

```
nodeos --genesis-json genesis.json
```

The genesis file for the mainnet looks like this:

```
{
  "initial_timestamp": "2018-06-08T08:08:08.888",
  "initial_key": "EOS7EarnUhcyYqmdnPon8rm7mBCTnBoot6o7fE2WzjvEX2TdggbL3",
  "initial_configuration": {
    "max_block_net_usage": 1048576,
    "target_block_net_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_net_usage": 524288,
    "base_per_transaction_net_usage": 12,
    "net_usage_leeway": 500,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_num": 20,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_den": 100,
    "max_block_cpu_usage": 200000,
    "target_block_cpu_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_cpu_usage": 150000,
    "min_transaction_cpu_usage": 100,
    "max_transaction_lifetime": 3600,
    "deferred_trx_expiration_window": 600,
    "max_transaction_delay": 3888000,
    "max_inline_action_size": 4096,
    "max_inline_action_depth": 4,
    "max_authority_depth": 6
  }
}
```

You'll also need the p2p addresses of a few people in your config.ini file.  For example:

```
p2p-peer-address = peering.mainnet.eoscanada.com:9876
```

Comment: So configure config.ini with p2p  peer address and run the nodeos with the genesis json file, that's it?

Comment: Yup, that's it.  nodeos knows what to do.  It reaches out to the peers, sees a matching chain, and starts sucking down blocks.  If you are running against the mainnet, consider the bnet plugin to increase your capacity to pull blocks from your peers and get your chain synced to the head block quickly

Answer (score 0):

Very good answer in the following link. 
I have succeeded by following this.

https://steemit.com/eos/@fundurian/learning-diary-connecting-to-eos-mainnet

Answer (score 0):

LiquidApps has a one pager that includes all downloads for Kylin/Mainnet:

https://docs.liquidapps.io/en/v1.3/dsps/eosio-node.html